# Robocopy do not copy is file exists in destination subfolders

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, robocopy

I have a script that copies files from a drop location onto a destination that I run from a VB.net app.

Current script with parameters:

```
   "C:\windows\SysWow64\robocopy.exe", TextBox1.Text & " " & TextBox2.Text & " /MT:50 /XC /XN /XO"
```

It does its job quite well but it has been brought to my attention that people working with the app would like to move the files into subdirectories in the same directory so they can keep track of what they have worked on.

Since this script is triggered to run every minute and I also have another one that moves processed files back to the drop location **I would like to know if there is a way that robocopy can search the destination and all its subdirectories for files with the same name so I avoid duplication.**

Thank you,

Doru

Comment: Not with an internal switch, no.  You'll have to script it.

Comment: I think I managed to do something with xcopy that has an /exclude:[filepath]. I have added a script that gets the folder content and then places it in a text file. It is set to a 10 second timer. The xcopy is set to a 1 minute timer. I will keep you posted. If you know of a better way please tell me :)

Comment: What robocopy lacks in functionality it gains in speed. With the /mt it would copy super fast. I don't know how to address this. It would be swell if I could use it's speed. I have to find a way to feed it a list of files to exclude

Comment: Well, there are `/xa`, `/xf` and `/xd` switches.  You could `for /R "destination" %%I in (*.mask) do set exclude=!exclude! "%%~nxI"` then use `robocopy /xf %exclude%`.  Be advised that the command line is limited to 8192 characters, though (if I recall correctly); so if you have a lot of files to exclude, this might not work.  If that's the case, you could `attrib +a sourcedir\%%~nxI` and use `robocopy /xa:a` (or is it `/xa:+a`?) to skip all files with the archive attribute set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to use an exclusion list for robocopy as follows:

1. I created a batch script that exports filenames in a txt file using this syntax:

   ```
   cd "**location of your files**"

   (for /r %%a in (*.jpg) do @echo %%~nxa) > C:\temp\EXCLUDE.txt
   ```

For more info see: [List files from folder includins subfolders batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474330/list-files-from-folder-includins-subfolders-batch)

2. Using this file I created a RCJ file (robocopy /job:filename.rcj)

   ```
   :: Include These Files :
   ::
   /IF     :: Include Files matching these names
   *.jpg   :: Include all names (currently - Command Line may override)
   :: Exclude These Files :
   /XF     :: eXclude Files matching these names

   **Names of files from the C:\temp\EXCLUDE.txt**
   ::
   /XO     :: eXclude Older files.
   /XN     :: eXclude Newer files.
   /XC     :: eXclude Changed files.
   ::
   /COPY:DAT   :: what to COPY for files (default is /COPY:DAT).
   ::
   /R:10       :: number of Retries on failed copies: default 1 million.
   /W:15       :: Wait time between retries: default is 30 seconds.
   /MT:10
   ```
3. After generating this file I use it as follows:

   ```
    "C:\windows\SysWow64\robocopy.exe", TextBox1.Text & " " & TextBox2.Text & " /job:C:\temp\filename.rcj"
   ```

I have set up the batch to run every 30 seconds to get filenames from folder and create the rcj file. Then, every 1 minute the robocopy job runs.

Big thanks to all the good people here at stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

[Robocopy Syntax, Flags and Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx)

Check out the above MicroSoft Link.  Robocopy has many flags to help achieve the results you are looking for.  Some that come to mind are:

- /x.. The exclude options in file selection
- /mir A mirror and purge
  option

Another site with some examples: [Robocopy Help](http://www.computerhope.com/robocopy.htm)

Comment: No option that I could find can do that in robocopy unfortunately. I replaced it with xcopy, even though it is slower from what I can tell as it has a /exclude:[filemane] option that parses a exclusion file.