# List files from folder includins subfolders batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am looking for a way to list all the .jpg files from a folder including subfolders. I know this can be done using:

```
dir *.jpg /s /a-d >> output.txt
```

Allthough the /a-d switch should remove the filepath, it does not do so when combined with the /s to check subfolders. So I do get a list but with the full path which I do not want.

I have also tried:

```
forfiles /m *.jpg /s > output.txt
```

This is really close to what I want but I get the file names between double quotes. This would normally not be a problem, but I use the file for a xcopy source destination /exclude:output.txt and it does not work with the quotes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `dir /a-d` doesn't "remove the filepath", but excludes folders from listing. 
I think, you are looking for the `/b` parameter: `dir /s /b *.jpg`. (of course you can add the `/a-d` in case there is any folder that ends with `.jpg`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be used inside a batch file

```
(for /r %%a in (*.jpg) do @echo %%~nxa) > output.txt
```

To use from command line

```
(for /r %a in (*.jpg) do @echo %~nxa) > output.txt
```

In both cases, it will recurse searching for `.jpg`  files and for each file found its name and extension are echoed. The full `for` command is enclosed in parenthesis and its output sent to the indicated file

Comment: Worked flawlesly! Thank you :)